# organic group drupal 7 views_get_views

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views, organic-groups

Trying to use views_get_views on the organic groups view *OG all user group content* to programmatically access the view using php. I am unable to set the parameter properly. I would like to get an example of working call.

Thanks,
Olivier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
/* load view object */
$views = views_get_view('og_all_user_group_content');
/* set default display */
$views->set_display('default');

/* pass group id as argument value */
$group_id =''; //set your group id here
$views->set_arguments(array($group_id));

/* execute view */
$views->execute();

/* result object */
if (!empty($views->result)) {
  if (count($views->result) > 0) {
    foreach ($views->result as $result) {
      //$result contain array of data.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was using "OG all user group content'

Comment: This works for 1 groupid. What if the user is a member of multiple groups? how do i pass the multiple groups ID?

Comment: you can create an array of groups. $group_id =array(1,2,3,4); //set your group id here
$views->set_arguments($group_id);